# Auto Increment field with starting value in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating a model given below. I want the student id to start from 100000 and then increment by 1.

```
class StudentLogin(models.Model):
  student_id = models.AutoField(min_value = 100000)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I am getting the following error if I use min_value `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_value'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
student_id = models.AutoField(min_value = 100000)
```

There is no min_value built in `AutoField` so you are having this error.use **default/Default** to set a min value.